# lateinit property preferenceFile has not been initialized if using outside the activity and fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to[Hilt] inject in the `PreferenceFile` into the class `TokenAuthenticator` but whenever trying to access, It throw me an error i.e  `lateinit property preferenceFile has not been initialized`

```
class TokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor() : Authenticator {
    @Inject
    lateinit var retrofitApi: RetrofitApi
    @Inject
    lateinit var preferenceFile: PreferenceFile

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        val refreshTokenIs = preferenceFile.retrieveKey(refreshToken)
        val responseRefresh = retrofitApi.refreshToken(refreshTokenIs ?: "")
        return if (responseRefresh.isSuccessful) {
            val newAccessToken = responseRefresh.body()
            preferenceFile.storeKey(token, newAccessToken?.token ?: "")
            preferenceFile.storeKey(refreshToken, newAccessToken?.refreshToken ?: "")
            preferenceFile.storeKey(tokenType, newAccessToken?.type ?: "")

            response.request.newBuilder()
                .header(AUTH_PARAM, "${newAccessToken?.type} ${newAccessToken?.token}")
                .build()
        } else {
            Log.e("sessionExpired", "===sessionExpired")
            MainActivity.context.get()?.sessionExpired()
            null
        }

    }
```

}

Below is `PreferenceFile` code

```
class PreferenceFile @Inject constructor(
    private val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor,
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) {
    fun storeKey(key: String, value: String) {
        editor.putString(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun storeBoolKey(key: String, value: Boolean) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun retrieveKey(key: String): String? {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, null)
    }

    fun retrieveBoolKey(key: String): Boolean {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)
    }

    fun <T> storeObject(key: String, data: T) {
        val jsonString = GsonBuilder().create().toJson(data)
        editor.putString(key, jsonString)
        editor.apply()
    }

    inline fun <reified T> getStoreObject(key: String): T? {
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null)
        return GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
    }


    fun clearPreference() {
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()
        //    openActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java), true)
    }

    /*
        fun retrieveLoginData(): LoginResponse {

            return Gson().fromJson(
                sharedPreferences.getString(loginDataKey, "")!!,
                LoginResponse::class.java
            )
        }
    */
}
```

Code of `PrefModule`

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class PrefModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getPref(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getEditor(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): SharedPreferences.Editor =
        sharedPreferences.edit()

}
```

If you need anything else apart from it. I will provide you.

Comment: When are you injecting it?  The preference is to use constructor injection, not field injection.  When you use field injection there needs to be a manual injection step, it's not done automatically.

Comment: @GabeSechan According to your suggestion, I've removed the construction injection and used the field injection. But still having not initialized issue.

Comment: These are not shown in provided codes (I suggest you add), but most likely the `editor` parameter is not (properly) setup as hilt injectable dependency. It's actually weird,  you can actually get rid of it just get it by `sharedPreferences.edit()` instead. Also show how you provide the sharedPreferences instance.

Comment: Looks alright. I now found the issue. It's the TokenAuthenticator itself. You can't do it that way since that is an implementation of an interface. You have to move its dependencies to its constructor and you need to provide an abstract function using @Binds

Answer (score 0):

```
class TokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor(
/*dependencies need to be constructor injected so hilt can instantiate*/
   retrofitApi: RetrofitApi,
   var preferenceFile: PreferenceFile 
) : Authenticator {

   //your codes..

}
```

```
//This effectively tells hilt which implementation to provide for Authenticator
@Module
@InstallIn(***Component::class)//set to appropriate scope based on where you will inject this
abstract class AuthenticatorModule {

  @Binds
  abstract fun bindAuthenticator(
    tokenAuthenticator: TokenAuthenticator
  ): Authenticator
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you said but it is not working. I need the TokenAuthenticator outside the fragment and activity.

Comment: Pls show how you injected it.  You may have to  change the scope of the module perhaps to SingletonComponent